I need to control the speed and direction of stepper motor through stepper motor and DAQ card
I am just a beginner in the world of LabVIEW and stepper motors. I am working on a coordinate measuring machine, which has a touch triggered probe and it moves on lead screws coupled with stepper motors. The stepper motor I have is NEMA-23 and it's microstepper driver being used is TB6600.
I want to program the motor in a way that the probe first moves at a reasonably fast pace while approaching the specimen (object to be measured) in order to make first contact. This touch will generate a pulse in the system. Once the first contact has been made, I want the probe to retract 3 mm, and then move ahead extremely slowly to make the second contact, at which instant the coordinates will be recorded. This is being done to ensure that precise readings are recorded.
I have a DAQ card available (NI-6009), and I have the DAQ-mx module installed in LabVIEW. How do I program this for the stepper motor on labview, so that I can control the motion completely from the computer (i.e the speed and direction of the motor).
Thank you!

Please note this is not a free coding service. Does tabview provide example code? What have you searched for?

Figure out your interfaces. What does your stepper driver need? What does your probe sensor provide? Get those controls and displays up in Labview. How long does it take to react to the sensor? What would an unacceptable crash of the probe be like? Based on those two, how fast can you go and still react before a bad crash?
